# Windows 10 VirtualDesktop/Task View in VB/C#

Tags: c#, windows, virtual-desktop

Referring to https://github.com/MScholtes/VirtualDesktop/issues/15

I'm looking to do 3 things programmatically, specifically:

1. How to activate task view, i.e. Win-Tab
2. How to deactivate task view
3. How to tell if we are currently in task view

I was able to bring up task view by running the following in a command prompt:

```
explorer shell:::{3080F90E-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}
```

But is starting a process in C# every single time I need task view the best approach? I prefer a programmatic way of calling some functions etc. I tried the following for activating, but it did nothing

```
public static readonly Guid CLSID_taskview = new Guid("3080F90E-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257");
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guids.CLSID_taskview));
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to do things that the user is supposed to be in control of.  Why are you trying to do these things programatically?   Why can't the user just press Win-Tab ?

Comment: Just moving the mouse to a corner to activate Task View is more productive than pressing Win-Tab

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to activate Task View without needing to launch a process:

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "shell:::{3080F90E-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

The same call can be used to deactivate it as well.

To see if the Task View is open, it looks like you can get a handle to the current foreground window and check its class name, like so:

```
bool IsTaskViewOpen() {
    WCHAR className[100];
    HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
    
    if (!foreground) {
        return false;
    }
    
    GetClassName(foreground, className, 100);
    return wcscmp(className, L"MultitaskingViewFrame") == 0;
}
```

I haven't tested that function extensively, so I don't know if it works in all cases.

Comment: isn't ```ShellExecuteA``` equivalent to launching a process? I was thinking along the lines of ```SendMessage``` etc

Comment: I don't think so. My understanding is that it communicates directly with the shell (i.e. the already running instance of explorer.exe) and sends it a command. It might involve launching a process depending on what shell command you tell it to execute, but in this case it's just telling explorer to toggle the Task View without having to start another explorer instance and passing it command line arguments.

Comment: I should add that after using this method for a while, I'm finding it to be unreliable. It's possible to get Windows into a state where using `ShellExecute` will no longer trigger the Task View. Also when it's in this state I can't use `ShellExecute` to show the desktop either. I'm not sure why, but I'm going to dig into it and research other methods.